# How to redirect windows command output to both console and file

Tags: windows, command-line

In windows I need to give a command similar to

```
  c:>dir > file.txt
```

But the I need the output both on the file.txt as well as on console. Is there any way to do this.

Comment: You could create a program to do the work. It would echo it's standard input to both standard output and the file(s) specified as it's arguments. Then pipe the output from any command into your program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Syntax is: **dir | batchtee file.txt**

This is a batch file tool designed by dbenham

```
::batchTee.bat  OutputFile  [+]
::
::  Write each line of stdin to both stdout and outputFile.
::  The default behavior is to overwrite any existing outputFile.
::  If the 2nd argument is + then the content is appended to any existing
::  outputFile.
::
::  Limitations:
::
::  1) Lines are limited to ~1000 bytes. The exact maximum line length varies
::     depending on the line number. The SET /P command is limited to reading
::     1021 bytes per line, and each line is prefixed with the line number when
::     it is read.
::
::  2) Trailing control characters are stripped from each line.
::
::  3) Lines will not appear on the console until a newline is issued, or
::     when the input is exhaused. This can be a problem if the left side of
::     the pipe issues a prompt and then waits for user input on the same line.
::     The prompt will not appear until after the input is provided.
::

@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
if "%~1" equ ":tee" goto :tee

:lock
set "teeTemp=%temp%\tee%time::=_%"
2>nul (
  9>"%teeTemp%.lock" (
    for %%F in ("%teeTemp%.test") do (
      set "yes="
      pushd "%temp%"
      copy /y nul "%%~nxF" >nul
      for /f "tokens=2 delims=(/" %%A in (
        '^<nul copy /-y nul "%%~nxF"'
      ) do if not defined yes set "yes=%%A"
      popd
    )
    for /f %%A in ("!yes!") do (
        find /n /v ""
         echo :END
         echo %%A
      ) >"%teeTemp%.tmp" | <"%teeTemp%.tmp" "%~f0" :tee %* 7>&1 >nul
    (call )
  ) || goto :lock
)
del "%teeTemp%.lock" "%teeTemp%.tmp" "%teeTemp%.test"
exit /b

:tee
set "redirect=>"
if "%~3" equ "+" set "redirect=>>"
8%redirect% %2 (call :tee2)
set "redirect="
(echo ERROR: %~nx0 unable to open %2)>&7

:tee2
for /l %%. in () do (
  set "ln="
  set /p "ln="
  if defined ln (
    if "!ln:~0,4!" equ ":END" exit
    set "ln=!ln:*]=!"
    (echo(!ln!)>&7
    if defined redirect (echo(!ln!)>&8
  )
)
```

Answer (score 1):

How about just echoing it?

```
dir > file.txt & type file.txt
```

Comment: this might work well for a simple command like `dir`, but if you have a long script that does a lot of work, then you will not see the output at the console during the execution, only after the script has finished.